# How to separate controller layer from server.ts in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I am using node.js with express for rest api and i have main file "server.ts" and i can write api routes in server.ts. But i wanna separate controller layer from server.ts even different controllers for their purpose. I have searched on google and found [link][1] for it.

[1]: http://bigspaceship.github.io/blog/2014/05/14/how-to-create-a-rest-api-with-node-dot-js/#toc_17  but i need this answer in typescript.

Comment: You could take advantage of the rich Typescript tutorial here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial

Comment: Your question is very vague... but it looks like you are actually looking for definitions files... not sure. please elaborate.